# How to Retrieve and Sort Contact List Alphabetically in React Native with User Permission?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I'm working on a React Native project and need to implement a feature that retrieves the user's contact list, including names and contact numbers, and sorts them alphabetically.
I want to ensure that I request the necessary user permissions for accessing contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-contact](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts) for this.

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
 console.log(contacts); // contacts returned
})
```